# Nothing changes on the client side until server side processing is finished

Tags: vaadin

I am editing a large vaadin web application's one upload page where the requirement is basically to upload a file and save its content. when its a small file there are no UX issues but for large files where there are say 1M rows (current production average), UX experience is pretty bad without at least any text like "processing...please wait". Just used `Button.setDisabledOnClick` in the "save button", but its not enough. User will have no clue what is happening, is there any error, should he cancel, etc.

this is the method code snippet (relevant part of method saveFile):-

```
    progressmsg.setVisible(true); // progressmsg is a label, initially setVisible(false)
    boolean msisdnInserted = rows.saveContent(); // inserts rows in batch in DB
```

this is called in no inappropriate way :-

```
    btnSave.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            saveFile();
        }
    });
```

problem is `progressmsg.setVisible(true)` is reflecting on browser after `rows.saveContent()` which does the inserts of the 1M rows in large files.

whatever I do I can't get the Label to be visible before the inserts start.
I even tried adding a 50x50 small window with a msg but behavior is same, window comes up after the processing.
Cannot figure this out after googling quite a bit. Any concept/suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing longer background processing tasks, it is good practice to process those on a separate thread to avoid blocking the main thread. You can then use a WebSocket connection and update the UI asynchronously when the backend task finishes. Here are some relevant docs https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access. This video also covers some good pointers on how to build performant UIs with Vaadin when you have long-running background tasks https://youtu.be/7Mr_pQc_rxA.

Essentially, what you want to do is do the processing in a separate thread, then use `ui.access()` to update the UI when you are done. You need to use `@Push` to update the UI from the server without an active request.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answers, solves a part of my problem. But my application is using vaadin 6.8.4. Can push be implemented on it? Upgrading just for one need will probably not be approved, hope you understand.

Comment: Push not a feature in Vaadin 6, it was introduced in Vaadin 7.x mid life. However there are some add-ons for Vaadin 6 to have a some sort Push solution, like this one https://vaadin.com/directory/component/icepush The Push feature in the recent versions of the framework is much better.

Comment: Note, Vaadin 6.8.4 is not even the latest Vaadin 6 series, I would recommend to upgrade to the lates. Also note Vaadin 6 is not maintained anymore, so there are no new releases coming to fix bugs or anything.

Comment: thanks @TatuLund, I used vaadin 7 and it woks perfectly according to the answer posted